# export error in ES6

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I have a file `MainContainer.jsx` in which I've written this code:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'

/**
 * Main Container, this will pass on all the Redux Store,
 * Router references to child elements.
 */
class MainContainer extends Component {
  /**
   * React Lifecycle Method: Renders the data
   *
   * @return {DOM} Main container DOM.
   */
  render() {
    return (
      <p>Hello world</p>
    )
  }
}

export default MainContainer
```

This is address to the file: `app/containers/Main/MainContainer.jsx`

I am trying to `export` everything present in `container` directory via `index.js` file. Here is the content of the file:

```
export MainContainer from './Main/MainContainer'
```

I've set `webpack alias` for `containers` directory as `$CONTAINERS`. Now I am trying to import `MainContainer` like this:

```
import MainContainer from '$CONTAINERS' // no need to pass the MainContainer full path, as it's being exported from index.js
```

Now I am getting build error at index.js:

```
 @ ./app/index.jsx 13:14-39
 @ multi (webpack)-dev-server/client?http://localhost:8080 webpack/hot/dev-server babel-polyfill ./app ./app/styles/main.css

ERROR in ./app/containers/index.js
Module build failed: SyntaxError: Unexpected token, expected { (1:7)

> 1 | export MainContainer from './Main/MainContainer'
    |        ^
  2 |

 @ ./app/config/routes.jsx 21:19-41
 @ ./app/index.jsx
```

Does anybody know what am I missing here...

Comment: ```export {MainContainer} from './Main/MainContainer'``` Try doing this.

Comment: I'm exporting `MainContainer` as `default`. Look at  the bottom of `MainContainer.jsx`. I don't think this will solve the issue.

Comment: Surroung your ```MainContainer``` with curly braces

Comment: But you need curly braces if you are not exporting it by default.

Comment: Oh I thought you were trying not to export it by default. Can you try one thing. do this ```import MainContainer from './Main/MainContainer';``` and then do ```export MainContainer``` does it still give the same error bro?

Comment: you don't have to `import` to `export`. Please checkout the `export` documentation.

Comment: You can either export something as default (then you should write 'default' instead of 'MainContainer' in index.js) or as a named export (then you need to use curly braces in index.js). You can't just 'pipe' the type of export through separate modules. MainContainer.jsx is a module (that has a default export) and index.js is a module (for which you have to decide if it should export a default or a named property).